# My friend wants to wire transfer money from overseas through my account. Do I get taxed for this?

Tags: international, transfer

So long story short, my friend is stuck overseas outside of U.S and in order to wire his money (about $8000-9000) through a bank, he has to do it in person for international wire transfers. My friend basically has this money stuck in a U.S based bank account and wants to transfer his money to himself and rightfully so. I can theoretically receive his money through my bank account and send his money back in person but I was not sure how taxes would work in this situation and whether I would have to pay for taxes? Any advice?

EDIT: for those of you asking yes this is real I talk to him on daily basis and this is confirmed. We are both noobs at this stuff and we had no idea how this all worked. Thank you for all your advice though, I learned something new today.

Comment: This sounds extremely scammy.  Have you ever actually met this "friend" in person?  Please consider the very real possibility you are being set up to be scammed and/or involved in illegal money laundering.

Comment: Pretty funny that on this board we immediately say "Your friend is a lie."

Comment: @OrangeCoast-reinstateMonica The situation described in the question does sound *exactly* like a scam setup that's been common for over a decade. My email won't even display messages that sound like this any more-- they go straight to the spam folder.

Comment: Right, CuriousJ should assume that the friend's email has been hacked, and that the request is fake.

Comment: Yes, agree with the others, your friend is either a scammer or has been hacked by one. "Talking every day" unfortunately doesn't mean anything in this case, it could even be a team of people working together.

Comment: Also, just in case you are wondering further how this could possibly work as a scam, the most likely result is that the account from which they will be wiring you money is actually hacked and belongs to another unwitting victim.

Comment: And finally... if you really don't believe us, try saying "Sorry, I've got cold feet about this and something just doesn't seem quite right. I can't help you out in this way after all, sorry." Stick to that for two or three days and don't engage in any discussions they will try to have to convince you it's not a scam. If they're a real friend, you'll know by the end of those 2-3 days.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what country is your "friend" supposed to be in?  I ask because in general it is not all that difficult to transfer money between US and foreign bank accounts, unless you're in one of those countries that has problems with the State Department.

Answer (score 5):

First, assume that the friend's email has been hacked, and that the request is fake.

If you can prove that the friend and the request are real, your friend could be more resourceful before asking for your help. E.g. there are many ways to transfer money that don't involve an international wire. Here's one: [Wise](https://wise.com/us/blog/international-ach-transfer)